# Showing a menu on long press iOS - Phonegap

Tags: javascript, iphone, cordova

I am new to phonegap. I have a list of images arranged as a grid (3*5). What I need is when make a long press on this image (a grid) a popup should shown. How can I implement this? Can anyone help me out to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may want to implement jQuery Mobile to solve your problem...

```
$( "img.galleryImage" ).on( 'taphold', function() {
    //Do your stuff here...
});
```

Have a look at the jQuery Mobile Documentation [here](http://api.jquerymobile.com/taphold/).

You also will be able to set the duration after which the action gets called.